# Alternate Solution for setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Tags: android, android-webview

I have developed an Android Application which uses Webview Component. I have used following line into my code,

```
webViewScores.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Due to this line it is showing Lint warning as `Using setJavaScriptEnabled can introduce XSS vulnerabilities into you application, review carefully.` Now I know that I can suppress this warning by  writing this line `@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")` above my method or at class level. But my question is, Is there any alternate solution for this ? I means is there any other way we can set Java Script Enabled in Webview ?

Answer (score 29):

you have to use it at Class Level like

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ...
}
```

and according to me there is no other way to enable `JavaScript` in `WebView`
and if your app really doesn’t require `JavaScript` usage within a WebView then don’t call setJavaScriptEnabled(true).

Comment: Suppressing a warning shouldn't be a solution.

Comment: @devDeejay That's true for most warnings which actually require some code-level remediation, but I feel this warning is a special case because it literally says "review carefully". If you have reviewed carefully and feel there's no risk in enabling JavaScript, I think it's valid to suppress the warning in order to denote that you have taken the action described by the warning (i.e. reviewed carefully)

Answer (score 5):

Be warned that setting setJavaScriptEnabled to true may result in refusal of your application submission on the Google Play Store, or if it's already there it may result in its removal.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7668153?hl=en

Comment: Best answer. Most of the time you use HTTPS with trusted servers, so switching off HTTP is a no-brainer.

Comment: This is only true if you are allowing access to file URLs or using plain HTTP, according to the link

Answer (score 2):

The warning tells You that enabling Javascript may be not secure.
Just check if You absolutely need to enable Javascript and if You need it, suppress warning by

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively implement a custom Javascript renderer or even better a full browser, after all, a browser only parses the html which is basically XML

Comment: Said implementation should definitely include liberal usage of regular expressions. It shall be called NIH-Browser.